# Rails: Where does this code belong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have the following in my controller:

```
@items = Item.scoped
@items = @items.where('price >= ?', params[:price_min]) if params[:price_min]
@items = @items.where('price <= ?', params[:price_max]) if params[:price_max]
@items = @items.where(:size => params[:size]) if params[:size]
@items = @items.where(:colour => params[:colour]) if params[:colour]
# ...
@items = @items.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

Is this the right place for this code, or should it really belong in my model with a single method call in the controller? i.e.

```
@items = Item.apply_filters(params)
```

I am trying to stick to convention as much as possible.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that this all belongs in your model. This is very similar to someone's code that I reviewed the other day. The MetaWhere gem might be a good fit for your project as well.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/500/how-to-filter-search-a-model-with-multiple-params-in-hash/501#501

Answer (score 1):

Also, if your items are always going to be scoped, you can make that the `default_scope`. In your model:

```
default_scope order("item_number"), where('price >= ?', 100)
```

(I'm not totally sure I got all of that syntax correct, but it's something like that.)

`named_scope` might also help you out.